# Angular2 can't find name 'AsyncRoutes' and 'IdleCallbacks'

Tags: angular, webpack, webstorm, angular2-routing, webpack-dev-server

I use Angular2 webpack with **WebStorm** and refer to this example:

https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/src/app/app.routes.ts

Why below code has '**red error prompt**'

```
import { WebpackAsyncRoute } from '@angularclass/webpack-toolkit';
import { RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';

export const asyncRoutes: AsyncRoutes = {

      //  **the error prompt is --TS2304 can't find name ' AsyncRoutes'**
    };

    export const prefetchRouteCallbacks: Array<IdleCallbacks> = [

      //   **the error prompt is --TS2304 can't find name 'IdleCallbacks'**
    ];
```

Comment: Have you added these in your package.json?  "@angularclass/webpack-toolkit": "^1.3.3", "@angularclass/request-idle-callback": "^1.0.7",

Comment: @Sanket yes , already add the **tow dependences** ,and can `import { WebpackAsyncRoute } from '@angularclass/webpack-toolkit';`

Comment: can't recreate (with Typescript compiler enabled, 'use tsconfig.json' is on). Just downloaded the project, installed dependencies and enabled compiler support. How do you compile it?

Comment: @lena in WebStorm , i have set **Typescript compiler enabled, 'use tsconfig.json' is on** and version --v1.8.10

Comment: I have just the same settings - no issues at all. Did you install all dependencies/typings?

Comment: @lena  i just **npm install** , and **npm start** to run the app

Comment: does **npm start** work (i.e. is your application built correctly when using this command)? what does you tsconfig.json look like? I'd suggest creating a support ticket

Comment: @lena  run **npm ls --can see typings@1.3.1** and tsconfig.json`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    //这里的内容 已经比较固定了,无需乱添加
    "target": "ES5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "filesGlob": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./test/**/*.ts",
    "!./node_modules/**/*.ts",
    "src/custom-typings.d.ts",
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ],

Comment: @lena `"awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }

}``

Comment: works for me using your config (note that it differs from the one on github). Seems your whole project is needed. Please create a support ticket

Comment: @lena  I just copy the common config file in here https://github.com/keryhu/angular2-issue